# button size are different in emulator from real device

Tags: android, xml, button, grid-layout

I am a beginner and I created 8 buttons on gridLayout.The size of buttons are different here is a xml code:

```
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="How are you"
        android:id="@+id/howareyou"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="good evening"
        android:id="@+id/goodevening"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="please"
        android:id="@+id/please"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="my name is"
        android:id="@+id/mynameis"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="do you &#10;speak english"
        android:id="@+id/doyouspeakenglish"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="welcome"
        android:id="@+id/welcome"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:text="i live in"
        android:id="@+id/ilivein"
        android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>

</GridLayout>
```

and here is the screenShot on Lg g3
[real device Lg g3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZPnU.png)

and here is the screenShot on emulator [emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY4Zj.png)

what is the problem?

Comment: your emulator and device Screen is different  thats why buttons size is changed @future2020

Comment: They look bigger in person.

Comment: Most of the properties your are using are introduced for API 21+ hence, the difference. You can even see it in the layout editor if your change the device android version

Comment: try to use text view in linear layout and weight than you get exact design in all devices

Comment: @DaminiMehra I know there are different that's why I'm using weight.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34694422/android-i-want-to-use-grid-layout-weight-under-21-api

Comment: Please remove following lines and try android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"

Comment: @Shaishav I'm learning from udemy android developer course and he used api 15.

Comment: So, you aren't getting any warnings in the xml layout for properties like `android:layout_columnWeight` and `android:layout_rowWeight`?

Answer (score 0):

you should fix your height and width of the button in dimension file for various resolution example:

**values folder:**

```
 <dimen name="width">90dp</dimen>
      <dimen name="height">75dp</dimen>
```

**values-hdpi folder:**

```
        <dimen name="width">100dp</dimen>
        <dimen name="height">85dp</dimen>
```

like this do for mdpi,,xhdpi,xxhdpi and put this in your button.

```
 android:layout_width="@dimen/width"
       android:layout_height="@dimen/height"
```

Answer (score 0):

try `LinearLayout` with `weightsum`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >

        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:id="@+id/hello"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="How are you"
            android:id="@+id/howareyou"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            />
   </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >

        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="good evening"
            android:id="@+id/goodevening"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="please"
            android:id="@+id/please"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            />



    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >

        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="my name is"
            android:id="@+id/mynameis"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="do you &#10;speak english"
            android:id="@+id/doyouspeakenglish"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            />



    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:padding="5dp"
        >

        <Button

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="welcome"
            android:id="@+id/welcome"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"
            />
 </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```